# Using R To Copy Files From Sharepoint

Tags: r, excel, sharepoint

We use SharePoint where sales people upload xls sheets with sales information in excel for the previous months work. The files are saved into folders based on the sales reps district so for example

```
Sales
   -> District One
   -> District Two
   -> District Three
```

The current situation is that an analyst will manually copy the files down and combine them into a single excel sheet. I thought i might automate this and then create a shiny dashboard to see a rolling weekly trend per district

I have tried something like below to get even a list of the filenames but it falls over

```
list.dirs(path = "https://foosharepoint/Sales", 
      full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

My question are:

- Is it possible to copy the files for the previous 6 months based on the modified date of the file. Can anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: I have figured out by mapping the drive in windows i was able to take the expected file path for sharepoint and it works very well to give me the list of folders. I can loop through this to get the excel files

So for example:

      `list.dirs(path = "https://foosharepoint/Sales@SSL/DavWWWRoot/", 
      full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE) `

I will add the loop for the excel files shortly once i have it figured out

Comment: What does "it falls over" mean?